# char ** then dereference to char *

Tags: c, pointers, casting

To compare string using library function, i learnt to write a comparison function to compare two strings, but im not really clear about why are they doing this.

```
int StrCmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    char *s1 = *(char**) a;
    char *s2 = *(char**) b;
    return strcmp(s1,s2);
}
```

Why do they have to cast it to char ** first?
why not just cast them to char * directly?
like

```
return strcmp((char*)a, (char*)b);
```

Whats the meaning of casting ( a pointer) to  ( a pointer to pointer) 
If i have

```
char *x = "string";
```

if i do casting for x

```
(char**)x; // what is this? Is this character 's'?
```

Im quite confuse with this, thanks for clarify
and one more question is about the const 
if it is a const, can i still cast them?(altought i know i can)

Comment: Where did you get this code? It looks obscenely hackish...

Comment: I think this must be a  `qsort` comparison function to sort strings...

Comment: This is indeed a wrapper, either for the qsort/bsearch kind of functions or just to preserve some interface or another. You must definitely write wrappers like this when passing an array of pointers to qsort/bsearch, if you pass the normal strcmp() the code will crash and burn.

Comment: Yep. Easy mistake to make since `strcmp` sounds like the perfect comparison function for a sort.

Comment: so can i just do return strcmp((char star)a, (char star)b) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Why do they have to cast it to (char pointer pointer) first? 
why not just cast them to (char pointer) directly?"

---

They have to cast it to what it is. Assuming the value
coming in points to memory location 10,000, you have
something like this:

```
  (char **) 

  a                 address a
                    "points to"
                    *a                **a   
  mem 1000          mem 10000         mem 20000
  to mem 1007       to mem 10007
  _____________     _____________     _______________ 
  pointer var  --> char pointer   ->  char
  10000             20000             'a'
  _____________     _____________     _______________
```

If you cast it to a (char *) you are telling the compiler
that the address referred to by a (in this case 10,000) is a char.
Which is not correct.

```
  (char *)          address a points 
  a                 to
  mem 1000          mem 10000         mem 20000
  to mem 1007
  _____________     ______            ________________
  pointer var  -->  "char"            unreachable char
  10000             ?                 'a'
  _____________     ______            ________________
```

---

"Whats the meaning of casting ( a pointer) to ( a pointer to pointer) If i have

char *x = "string";
if i do casting for x

(char**)x; // what is this? Is this character 's'?"

---

What exists in this example is something like:

```
x            *x or x[0] x[1]       x[2]      x[3]      x[4]      x[5]      x[6]
mem 15000    mem 30000  mem 30001  mem 30002 mem 30003 mem 30004 mem 30005 mem 30006
to 15007
char *       char       char       char      char      char      char      char
_________    _________  _________  _________ _________ _________ _________ _________

30000    -->    's'       't'         'r'      'i'      'n'       'g'       '\0'
________     _________  _________  _________ _________ _________ _________ _________
```

If you tell the compiler that x is a char** then it thinks this
is the pattern:

```
x              *x or x[0]         **x
               char *
mem 15000      mem 30000          "char" 
to 15007       to 30007
__________     _________          _________

30000      --> "string\0?"
               converted to
               pointer value  ->   ??
__________     _________          _________
```

It incorrectly ends up going to whatever "address" the first 8 bytes starting at 30000 resolves to and getting a "character". But since 30000 is the
start of a null-terminated character array, at best it goes to some part of memory and gets some random byte, thinking it is a valid char. At worst it will get an address that is invalid for this program, causing a fatal error when it tries to access it.

---

so can i just do

```
 return strcmp((char *)a, (char *)b);
```

---

No, because a and b are not char pointers. To get char pointers you can't avoid:

```
return strcmp( *(char**)a, *(char**)b);
```

Using Linden's example you would call like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int StrCmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    char *s1 = *(char**) a;
    char *s2 = *(char**) b;
    printf("s1:%s\n",s1);
    printf("s2:%s\n",s2);
    return strcmp(s1,s2);
}

const char* arr_of_ptr[] =
{
  "hello",
  "world"
};

const char **p_arr_of_ptr = arr_of_ptr;

int main(void)
{
   const char *cstring1 = "LaDonna";
   const char *cstring2 = "McPherson";
   const char **pcstring1 = &cstring1;
   const char **pcstring2 = &cstring2;
   StrCmp(&arr_of_ptr[0],&arr_of_ptr[1]);
   StrCmp(pcstring1,pcstring2);
   StrCmp(p_arr_of_ptr,p_arr_of_ptr + 1);
}
```

Comment: when i pass two strings to this function StrCmp("apple", "Orange"). I got segmentation fault, is my code correct? oh.. i seems like understand a bit more. But im still confused by these stuff

Comment: No. You need to put the strings in an array the way Lundin did in his example.

Comment: So.. what we better do is, cast to what it supposed to be first. and then cast to what we wanna it be

Comment: @TimothyLeung Cast to what it is and then "dereference" to get what it points (or refers) to. A cast and then a dereference. Not a cast followed by cast.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the caller of that function is using an array of pointers, such as:

```
const char* arr_of_ptr[] =
{
  "hello",
  "world"
};
```

In that case, the first element of the array is a pointer to a char, it is not a char in itself. Therefore the StrCmp function acts as a translator between the array of pointers to normal C strings.

However, they are also casting away the const keyword, which is bad practice. The function should be written like this:

```
int StrCmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    const char *s1 = *(const char**) a;
    const char *s2 = *(const char**) b;
    return strcmp(s1,s2);
}
```

[Good reading on the topic](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively casting a void pointer (ie: `void*`) to double pointer to char (ie: `char**`).

Remember that the indirection/de-referencing operator (unary `*` operator) and the type casting operator (eg: `(char**)`) have the same precedence, but also right-to-left associativity.

So, consider the following:

```
void myFunction(void* a) {
  char* s1;  // Pointer to a character, or the beginning of a character array or string
             // Note that the effective difference between a character array and a string is that
             // a string is a character array that is terminated with the '\0' character
  s1 = *(char**) a;
             /* The above statement can be decomposed as follows:
              * (  *( (char**) a ) )
              * 1) Cast the pointer-to-void-type, (ie: void*)'a', 
              *    to a pointer-to-pointer-to-char (ie: char**)
              * 2) Deference the value, so it becomes a pointer-to-char
              * 3) Assign this char* value to s1
              */
}
```

This is very common in C where you have to do some nifty pointer magic because the language does not support templates like its successor C++. Mind you, if you can work with advanced pointer logic, there's probably no need for you to use C++ in place of C anyways.

Good luck!